# chromiumembedded custom cache directory not working

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, caching, chromium, chromium-embedded

I am developing a standalone application of my web application using chromiumembedded. I want to store my cache in hard drive so that next time user load it should be faster. I have added following lines to cefsimple_win.cpp after the line `CefSettings settings;`

```
const char* path = "D:\C++HTML5\test";


CefString(&settings.cache_path).FromASCII(path);
```

But no files are stored in the specified path. Please let me know what is wrong with this approach

Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
const char* path = "D:\\C++HTML5\\test";
```